# How to handle vue 404 on refresh?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Okay so I am teaching myself vue and I am wondering while using vue router what is the conventional way for handling `404` errors on page refresh? I tried using `mode:"hash"` and it is working nicely but I want this site to be more SEO friendly therefore I want to use `mode:"history"` in my `VueRouter`. Should I force redirect to home page on refresh via JS or is there a better and smarter way to handle this?
P.S Just to mention since there can be slight difference in code I am doing this in laravel

Comment: you need to set up the *server* correctly when using `mode: "histroy"` - what do you use as a http server?

Comment: I was trying something similar, just to try something new, and I ended up using `Route::view('/{any?}', 'layout');` as my last route. See that `layout` should be your **ONLY** view, where you load your SPA (Vue) and then do whatever you need. So, to handle 404, you should create a `404` page and when Vue router sees that the page does not exist, redirect to that Laravel `404` route, or manually create it in Vue and let Vue handle that (client side) instead of handling it through Laravel. And if the route is an API, there should be no problem, as you define my route in `web.php`.

Comment: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I use apache, and I was looking for the link last night that Michal sent I knew I saw it somewhere but could not find it again. Also what matiaslauriti said sounds like a reasonable solution. I fixed my problem with `mod_rewrite.c` , but if any of you want to answer I'd be happy to accept it